# Error "expected string or buffer"

Tags: python, arabic, python-imaging-library, bidi, ligature

I am generating images of 2 character permutations and using `arabic_reshaper` for joining characters. Permutation of 2 for 2 character will generate 4 images but `arabic_reshaper` is generating error `"Expected String or buffer"` at t1 =  `arabic_reshaper.reshape(word).`
Please ask if question is not clear.

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageFont, PIL.ImageDraw
import arabic_reshaper

unicode_text = u"\u06F1"+ u"\u06CC"+ u"\u06A9"
list_of_letters = list (unicode_text)
folder = 1
n=2
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for word in itertools.permutations( list_of_letters,i):
        print word
        t1 =  arabic_reshaper.reshape(word)
        print t1
        img= PIL.Image.new("L", (200, 200))
        draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        font = PIL.ImageFont.truetype( r"C:\Users\arabtype.ttf", 40)
        t2 = get_display(t1)      
        print t2# <--- here's the magic <---
        draw.text( (10,50), ' ' + t2, fill=220, font=font)
        img.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `itertools.permutations` produces a tuple.

You need to convert it to string. Something like this:

```
for word in itertools.permutations( list_of_letters,i):
    word = u''.join(word)
    print word
```